# When exactly is it safe to close a boost asio tcp socket?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have an application that connects to a tcp socket asynchronously using:

```
basic_socket::async_connect
```

The socket is closed using:

```
socket.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both)
socket.close()
```

Writing to the socket is carried out using:

```
boost::asio::write
```

I have been investigating an issue where an exception is thrown from 
boost::asio::write. This then invokes a destructor which closes the socket using the process above. When this happens I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'myexceptionclass<boost::system::error_code>'
```

This arises from the exception thrown during the socket write. This results in:

```
16591 Aborted    (core dumped)
```

Aside: The reason this is occurring is due to the following asio issue: https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/8795. If I start the server and then immediately start my client, it does not detect correctly that sometimes the server is not fully initialised, goes ahead with the write and then throws the exception. The issue, in this context, only occurs infrequently.

The fix that I have put in place is to just to detect the exception at the low level (around the write) and if it has been thrown then don't shutdown the socket (I'm assuming that this has occurred automatically). However, I'm not completely happy with this fix.

Now my question: If an exception is thrown from the socket write does this mean that the socket will in all cases not require an explicit shutdown? Or in other words: Can an exception be thrown from the write function and the socket still require an explicit shutdown? Basically, when can I know exactly when an explicit shutdown is required?

Comment: Why don't you just catch the exception ? the `boost::asio::write` just send it to tell, "yeah the socket has been close, I can't write it anymore". Would be mush better to understand with a [mcve].

Comment: I do, that's where the problem comes from. I had to completely refactor my design to fix this issue. Might post an answer later.